# Regression error increase after shuffing data

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I'm trying to do multivariate regression using a 3-dimension data set. I noticed a strange problem that my fitting error increase dramatically after I pre-shuffled the data matrix comparing using original data. Is that possible? I've checked my code and confirmed that it's the shuffled process that increased the error. Why is that? Shouldn't shuffle process only change the order of the data?

Comment: How is your train and test split? Maybe the data was somehow ordered before splitting? If you can give more details on the validation method, that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to shuffle the whole dataset together before separating the features (X) and target variable (y). This is the only reason I can think of for getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing k-fold cross-validation, that might happened. Otherwise, I think, it is not logical to have such a change. If you share your code, it would be easier to find the source of the problem.